# Using a Resources/drawable file as small icon for Notifications in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms project I have a file `icon.png` in each of the Resources/drawable folders of the droid project. BuildAction is AndroidResource.  I use this file in various places in the project and they appear just fine.

Now I am trying to use it as the small icon for notifications. In the PCL project the small icon is set like this in the example code I am using:

```
.SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail)
```

I was sort of expecting `icon` to be shown in the Resource.Drawable Intellisense chooser, but it is not, so `Android.Resource.Drawable.icon` results in `'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'icon'`.

I tried adding a resx file to the PCL project, but VS will only let me add strings to that file, not images.

How do I use `icon` instead of `SymActionEmail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Resource.Drawable.icon` instead of `Android.Resource.Drawable.icon`. With the Android prefix, you're referring to [this list](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Resource+Drawable/) of predefined resources, not the ones in your project.

**Edit:** Instead of commenting, I decided to write here because it's easier to read.

[SetSmallIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int,%20int)) is a method in the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class from the Android API. You should never call platform specific code directly from the PCL project. Also, that's the reason you shouldn't even be able to call `Android.Resource.Drawable` resources from the PCL. Have you added a reference to Xamarin.Android or something?

The correct way to call platform specific code from a  PCL is to (for example) create an interface in the PCL, which is then implemented in each platform specific project. Here's an excerpt from the Xamarin documentation:

> Using either interfaces or base classes defined in the shared code and implemented or extended in platform-specific projects. Writing and extending shared code with class abstractions is particularly suited to Portable Class Libraries because they have a limited subset of the framework available to them and cannot contain compiler directives to support platform-specific code branches.
>
> [Handling Platform Divergence & Features](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/#Platform_Abstraction)

Also, to your question about setting the notification inside the PCL: *Doesn't setting the notification inside one of the platform specific projects sort of break the purpose of using Xamarin.Forms in the first place?*

In short, no it doesn't. Xamarin.Forms isn't meant to be able to do everything in a single project, that's why you still have separate projects for iOS, Android and UWP. Anything that requires platform specific libraries or functinality should be implemented in the platform specific project but can still be called from the PCL by using abstraction.

Comment: `'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Drawable'`

Comment: @davecove Are you trying to do that within the PCL project? You don't have a reference to the Android project in your PCL so that can't be done. You need to set the notification in the Android project and then `Resource.Drawable.icon` will work just fine.

Comment: @davecove If that's not the case, could you link to the example code or post it fully here?

Comment: @davecove I edited my answer. You need to use abstraction to create a notification interface in the PCL which is then implemented in each platform specific project. Android resources are not available from the PCL as the same code will run on iOS and would obviously fail when there's a call to `Android.Resource.Drawable` etc.

Comment: I am such an idiot. I only _thought_ I was doing this in the PCL.  I am in fact doing it in the Android project. **>DOAH!<**  I am following the Microsoft example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#update-the-server-project-to-send-push-notifications), which works except when I try to use `Resource.Drawable.icon` which results in `'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Drawable'`.